# Php header security concert when using it?

Tags: php, security

```
 header(string,replace,http_response_code);

  * string  Required. Specifies the header string to send
  * replace Optional. Indicates whether the header should replace previous or add a second header. Default is TRUE (will replace). FALSE (allows multiple headers of the same type)
  * http_response_code      Optional. Forces the HTTP response code to the specified value (available in PHP 4.3 and higher)
```

what should I concern about securiy when using this functon?

Comment: In what way?  "Security" is a huge topic and without specifics a question like this just can't be sensibly answered.

Comment: Once upon a time this function was vulnerable to CRLF injection,  but other than that,  the print() and echo() functions are far more dangerous in terms of security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically as long as you don't allow any user-supplied content to get into the header, you should be safe.